# Prove that nuclear norm of a matrix is equal to the sum of squares of Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition, nuclear-norm

Nuclear norm of a matrix is defined as the sum of the singular values of the matrix.

I saw a Lemma (without any proof) claiming

$$
\|X\|_\sigma = \min_{X=UV'} \|U\|\|V\| = \min_{X=UV'} \frac{1}{2}(\|U\|^2 + \|V\|^2)
$$
where $\|.\|_\sigma$ is the nuclear norm of $X$ and $\|.\|$ is the Frobenius norm.

Where can I find the proof of this proposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Let $X=PSQ'$ be a singular value decomposition of $X$. If $UV'=X$, then
$$
\|X\|_\sigma
=\operatorname{tr}(S)
=\operatorname{tr}(P'UV'Q)
\le\|P'U\|_F\|Q'V\|_F
=\|U\|_F\|V\|_F
\le\frac12(\|U\|_F^2+\|V\|_F^2).
$$
Since ties occur when $U=PS^{1/2}$ and $V=QS^{1/2}$, the conclusion follows.